# Does Zoro still have his ankle scars from Little Garden?

Tags: one-piece

In Chapter 133, Zoro appears to have received ankle scarring from Little Garden, yet in Chapter 239, there's no scarring, so does this mean the scarring wasn't permanent, or was it an error?

[image: Chapter 133]

[image: Chapter 239]

Answer (score 1):

Probably just an error. There are many if you look carefully. Once I saw one of Luffy's hands have only four fingers.

Answer (score 1):

The ankle scarring you see is on the left leg, which is not completely visible because of the clouds in the bottom image. Probably that's why we can't see it.
As per chapter-122 Page-20, we see that the sword on the left leg is blooded, so not sure whether the right leg was also scarred at that moment.